# How to display special characters in input elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, htmlspecialchars

I want to set placeholder with special characters for an input. Thus, this is my code:

```
input.attr('placeholder', '&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;');
```

This outputs special char codes instead of special characters. What is the correct way to display special characters in input elements using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input>` elements use **plain text**, not html, so don't overcomplicate your life :)

Just:

```
input.placeholder="●●●●●";
```

Comment: Thank you very much @nicael! Will accept the answer in 10 mins.

Comment: @Bravo And edited to provide even more simpler way :)

Comment: Thank you once again! That looks very clean!

Answer (score 1):

Just use HTML interpreter for the same,

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = "&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;";
input.setAttribute("placeholder", d.innerText);
```

Comment: Main problem as far as I understand is that placeholder was showing &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; instead of ●●●●●

Comment: Ah, got it. But it is far too complicated. [Inputs use plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29182744/2963652), so there's a much simpler way to achieve this task.

Comment: this creates new div not in DOM, unless I append it as child to any element in DOM it won't be live in page.
also it takes care of the fact that HTMLCodes might be coming from some service